# Meteor: how to call a function with 2 parameters and wait for the result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, async-await

I have been reading about [promises](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/writing-asynchronous-code-in-meteor-and-javascript), [wait/async](https://forums.meteor.com/t/start-using-async-await-instead-of-promises-and-callbacks/17037/51) and [fibers](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-fibers-and-meteor-asyncwrap-work/6087?page=2) for the last couple of days but I still can't wrap my head around it yet. I am having a hard time to find a simple example that shows how I can make something like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  theMethod: function(){
    var numberOne = 4;
    var numberTwo = 5;
    var result = calculateNumber(numberOne, numberTwo);
    console.log('This is the result: ', result);
  }
});

calculateNumber = function(numberOne, numberTwo){
  var result = numberOne + number Two
  //but lets assume an ultra complex calculation that takes a while
  return result;
}
```

How can I make the console.log wait for the result to come back without a callback but the await/wrapAsync syntax?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

Here is the code that I tried:

```
Meteor.methods({
  theMethod: async function(){
    const no1 = 4, no2 = 5;
    //calculateNumber should return a promise, if it doesnt, Promise.resolve makes the returned value a promise
    const calculateNumberPromise = Promise.resolve(calculateNumber(no1, no2));
    const res = await calculateNumberPromise;
    console.log('Number calculated', res);
    //the number can be returned directly to the client:
    return res
  }
});

calculateNumber = function(no1, no2){
  function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }
  sleep(5000).then(() => {
    return no1 + no2;
  });
}
```

Is there a way to just make everything wait that comes after the calculateNumber? If that is not possible, where/how do I have to nest the console.log to make it wait?

Comment: The code you posted should work as expected and the console log should output the result of calculateNumber. I'm under the impression that calculateNumber is a synchronous function based on the example.

Comment: The function is not synchronous. That is specified in the question.

Comment: @DerrickGremillion console log will return undefined if the calculateNumber function takes long, and aparently I can add some await somehow in there, but just writing `var result = await calculateNumber(numberOne, numberTwo);` was not enough..

Comment: @SebMorris, do you know how to make it synchronous? :))

Comment: im writing an answer :D

Comment: The function you've added is synchronous. The only use of wrapAsync is when an asynchronous functions takes a callback argument with (err, res) arguments. It would be useless in the case of your example function

Answer (score 3):

With exclusively `Promise` (ie no `async`/`await`), you can do something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  theMethod: () => {
    const no1 = 4, no2 = 5;
    //calculateNumber should return a promise, if it doesnt, Promise.resolve makes the returned value a promise (unless calculateNumber is a sync function ie takes a callback)
    const calculateNumberPromise = Promise.resolve(calculateNumber(no1, no2));
    //If you want to log the output regardless:
    calculateNumberPromise
    .then(res => console.log('Number calculated', res))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error calcualting number', err))
    //The promise is resolved before the data is sent over the wire.
    return calculateNumberPromise;
  }
});
```

On the client this method can then be called and the promise be used. Ideally you should use [validated methods](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method) now. In conjunction with validated methods, you can use the [callPromise mixin](https://atmospherejs.com/didericis/callpromise-mixin). Examples linked. More [validated method examples](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html) can be found in the meteor guide.

Adapting the previous snippet to use `async` is simple:

```
Meteor.methods({
  theMethod: async function() {
    const no1 = 4, no2 = 5;
    //calculateNumber should return a promise, if it doesnt, Promise.resolve makes the returned value a promise
    const calculateNumberPromise = Promise.resolve(calculateNumber(no1, no2));
    const res = await calculateNumberPromise;
    console.log('Number calculated', res);
    //the number can be returned directly to the client:
    return res;
  }
});
```

Notice the addition of `async` in the function definition. An **excellent** writeup can also be found [here](https://medium.com/@robfallows/meteor-promises-fdd1f701caf1) - check out Rob Fallows other articles.

`wrapAsync` is simple enough, but i would suggest sticking to `Promise` and `async`/`await`. If you really want to use it, some old (but good) examples can be found on the [Meteor chef's site](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/synchronous-methods).

If any of that was unclear, please ask for clarification.

Comment: I now used this `  function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }
  sleep(3000).then(() => {` to slow down the execution of calculateNumber. Then both versions above did not help and the `console.log('Number calculated', res);` printed with res = undefined and later calculateNumber printed it was done now. How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the rest of that code segment? The sleep function code is fine, however only code inside the then chain will run after 3 seconds. Furthermore, if the console.log is outside of the then chain, it run before the wait, hence printing `undefined`.

Comment: This is becoming more of a promise misunderstanding question than a meteor question. From the calculate number function you are not returning the promise chain. Therefore the method doesn't wait for the sleep and calculation

Comment: I suggest reading up more on promises. The YDKJS book: 'Async and performance' is excellent and free to read on GitHub. The other books in this series are also very worth checking out

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make an async function synchronous in Meteor is to wrap it with [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync)

For your example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  theMethod() {
    const numberOne = 4;
    const numberTwo = 5;
    const result = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncFun(numberOne, numberTwo));
    console.log('This is the result: ', result);
  }
});
```

Your `calculateNumber` function is synchronous the way you've listed it in your question, `wrapAsync` is designed to wrap a truly async function. Note that *long running* !== asynchronous. Note also that the async function you're wrapping must return an error and a result, not just a result. Of course when you use `wrapAsync` only the result will be returned to the calling code so you'll need to use a `try/catch` block to catch any errors.

Comment: could you explain to me, why calculateNumber is synchronous? I thought if it will take a very long time to execute, then it will not block. I tried it with slowing down calculate Number by 5 seconds and then result is undefined when printed..

Comment: Async functions have a *callback*. `calculateNumber` does not. Since you're doing all this on the server you also need to consider [this.unblock()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock)